# apt install lamp-server - MySQL password

Tags: server, mysql, lamp

I have installed lamp-server via command

```
apt install lamp-server
```

and it works, as I see in the web browser.
But I am not able to log in to mysql as root user. If I try to run

```
mysql -u root -p
```

it asks me for a password, but nothing is good enough for her. I tried empty string and also root... The installation process didn't ask me for a root password, so I'm a little confused what I should do in this case.

Comment: So as I wrote the question I tried **sudo** mysql -u root -p with empty string and it works.

Comment: when did you install lamp with that command, on what version of Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo mysql -u root` and you should be logged in to mysql without a password